# How to write "if...else" mod_rewrite statements in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've scoured StackOverflow for an answer to this and seen many questions come close, but nothing is working for me yet.

I'd like to have my `.htaccess` apply different rules based on the domain calling it.  Basically, if subdomain.example.com is hit, redirect to google.com.  If localhost is hit, redirect to yahoo.com.  If www.example.com (or example.com) is hit, redirect to bing.com.

I'll be adding in actual rewrite rules (setting environment variables and htpasswd protection) later, but first I need to get the "if then" part working.

My (non-working) code is below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule http://google.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule http://yahoo.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule http://bing.com/ [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT: Updated (but still non-working) code based on Barta's comment below.**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S=7]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/www/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_DB_HOST:localhost]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_DB_NAME:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_USERNAME:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_PASSWORD:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=BASE_URL:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENVIRONMENT:XXX]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Actually your question has been answered, but you have other misconfiguration problems, in which I also try to help.

Answer (score 9):

You might find this useful if you are using Apache 2.4.

My server sets an environment variable `HTTPS` if connecting via HTTPS, though there are different ways to pick up on it. My goal was to force HTTP authentication, but only on a secure connection and redirect non-secure connections to the secure location.

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
  AuthName "Files are protected, enter your normal website email and password"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/sites/mysite.co.uk/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</If>
<Else>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</Else>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to rewrite http://bing.com to [L,R=301] instead of anything to http://bing.com with the [L,R=301] flags. Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://bing.com/ [L,R=301]`

About IF-ELSE: Use the S flag on your RewriteRule like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .? - [S=<here comes the number of your directives in the "else" part>]
# Here comes your ELSE part:
# Etc. etc.
RewriteRule .? - [S=<here comes the number of your directives in the "if" part>]
# Here comes your IF part.
```

In the example above if your RewriteCOnd is matched, then the RewriteRule with the S flag skips the following directives and stops the skipping after the Nth skip where N is defined after the S= part. This is your ELSE part. The N number should include your next RewriteRule that skips the IF part.

They are in reversed order, because of the skipping. If you negate the RewriteCond, then they're ok in normal order.

Here's the original example in Apache docs:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s

**Edit:**
Try something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule .? - [S=7]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/www/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_DB_HOST:localhost]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_DB_NAME:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_USERNAME:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MYSQL_PASSWORD:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=BASE_URL:XXX]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ENVIRONMENT:XXX]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The original Apache example you linked to shows the IF statements first and then the ELSE statements, so they're in regular order.  You said they should be in reverse order.  Why?

Comment: I've tried what you (and the Apache example) suggested, and still no dice.  My updated code is above in my original question.  Any ideas?

Comment: Because in that example the expression checked is negated. They say there !-d where ! is the negation. So it's like saying: if (what I don't want) { // be sad } else { // be happy } instead of if (what I want) { // be happy } else { // be sad }

Comment: Why did you put in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`? Do you want to check for the requested URL not to be an existent file? You can't negate your previous RewriteCond with it. You have to put the `!` in the first one.
Like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$`

Comment: I'm confused why that matters.  if (false) { do this for false; } else { do this for true; } is the same as if (true) { do this for true; } else { do this for false; } in the sense that the action for the if immediately follows the if.

That's what I have in my edited example above.

Comment: I updated with an example. I think now you get the idea. :) Sorry, if my explanation was confusing for you.

Comment: All I want is a simple if/else statement:

If (domainA) {
   apply these rules;
} else if (domainB) {
   apply these rules;
} else if (domainC) {
   apply these rules;
}

Comment: I tried your example but still no dice.  Still getting "The requested URL /index.php/ was not found on this server."

Comment: Are you using some sort of MVC framework? Is your document root pointed to a directory, where its index.php can be found? Do you have `Options MultiViews` in your config for that directory (to have index.php/blablabla found as index.php)? Are you sure you don't need a `RewriteBase /`?
This whole thing starts to be too specific for you. The if/else thing I guess is answered, since it works on my setup. Maybe we could continue in chat, like stackoverflow advises?

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using an MVC framework - CodeIgniter.  Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation for the chat. :(

Comment: As a last advice:
Make sure you have `MultiViews` in your `Options` directive on the directory that has the framework. Try `RewriteBase /` before the index.php rewrites. If your document root points to the root of CodeIgniter, and not to its public folder (I use FuelPHP its named public in that, in CodeIgniter it can be different, I mean the directory with index.php), then use `RewriteBase /public`.
Mod_rewrite can be tricky...
If it fails to solve, then try debuging mod_rewrite yourself.
`RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"`
`RewriteLogLevel 10`