# .htaccess if-then-like selective rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
##### PART 1

# IF:
RewriteRule ^ac$ /ac05182018.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
# THEN:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/downloads/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(pdf))$ downloads/$1 [L]

##### PART 2

# IF:
RewriteRule ^ac64$ /ac64_05182018.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
# THEN:
RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf)$ download.php?file=$1.$2 [L]
```

"**PART 1**" works standalone (= if one requests **http...mysite.com/ac** then this rewrites to "**http...mysite.com/downloads/ac05182018.pdf**").

"**PART 2**" works standalone as well (= if one requests **http...mysite.com/ac64** then this rewrites to "**http...mysite.com/download.php?file=ac64_05182018.pdf**").

*I was wondering how to achieve the following*:

**I need both of them (PART 1 & 2) to be combined**, so that either one will be executed, I mean that both work, depending on what file gets requested (either **/ac** or **/ac64**).

When I do so though, "PART 1" no longer rewrites to "/downloads/ac05182018.pdf" and then stops executing the rest. Instead it rewrites to "http...mysite.com/download.php?file=downloads/ac05182018.pdf"...

Any idea how to achive this?
Something like:

```
# IF:
RewriteRule ^ac$ /ac05182018.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
# THEN:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/downloads/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(pdf))$ downloads/$1 [L]

# ELSE

# IF:
RewriteRule ^ac64$ /ac64_05182018.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
# THEN:
RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf)$ http...mysite.com/download.php?file=$1.$2 [L]
```

Maybe with RewriteRule flag [S] or

```
<If ... >
...
</If>
<Else>
...
</Else>
```

as both seen in the answers of [How to write "if...else" mod_rewrite statements in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528634/how-to-write-if-else-mod-rewrite-statements-in-htaccess) ?

Answer (score 0):

First this line `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/downloads/$1 -f` will prevent next rule `RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|pdf))$ downloads/$1 [L]` to be executed because you don't have downloads yet in document root .

After remove it , there will be two rules to `.pdf` files :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpe?g|pdf))$ downloads/$1 [L]
```

and this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).(rar|zip|pdf)$ http...mysite.com/download.php?file=$1.$2 [R,L]
```

Unless you do some conditions one of them both will match `.pdf` and that will give error .

Moreover , don't forget to to put `L` flag like here :

```
RewriteRule ^ac64$ /ac64_05182018.pdf [R=301,NC]
```

it should be `RewriteRule ^ac64$ /ac64_05182018.pdf [R=301,NC,L]`

L flag means if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

If i understand you your code should be like this :

```
 RewriteEngine On

 #Part 1
 RewriteRule ^ac$ /ac05182018.pdf [R=302,NC,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(downloads|ac64)
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(jpe?g|pdf)$ /downloads%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

 #part 2
 RewriteRule ^ac64$ /ac64_05182018.pdf [R=302,NC,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !downloads
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(rar|zip|pdf)$ /download.php?file=$1.$2 [L]
```

Clear browser cache and test it , if it is ok , change any `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection .

**Note:** any `.pdf` files not start with `ac64` will be treated by the `ac` rule , first rule .

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately this does not work, both times, it redirects to the PDF in Part2 it should redirect to the download.php instead...

Comment: if reuest start with ac64 only will go part 2 , did you clear cache? paste a tested request?

Comment: My standard browsers are Chrome & Firefox, so when I check code that needs to clear cache etc. I use the vivaldi browser with a incognito tab instead. That should do the trick, be the same as clearing cache, isnt it? I just rechecked with ac64 first and it still does not redirect to downloads.php ...

Comment: ac64 will redirect to download.php not downloads.php , this is what understand from your code and ac will redirect to downloads

Comment: Yes sorry, my spelling mistake on the last reply. Still, it does not work. I will rebuild and recheck all tonight. Thanks so far!

Comment: Ok, let me ask you , you want to redirect externally or internally ? i meant i understood you want to show file.pdf and internally redirect those files to different paths , if you want to redirect externally i should change this code , let me know

Comment: I dont know what you mean by externally/internally. I updated the INFO above, hope this makes it clearer. Basically both parts work separately, I want them to work combined in one htaccess...

Comment: try to change any [L]  with [R=302,L]  then see if that what you are looking for , it means you finally want external redirection

Comment: sorry, i just had the time to make some extensive tests, also added your last suggestion, still it does not work. I will update my explanation above to try and make it even more clear!