# How to attach same RewriteCond to different RewriteRule in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect url to my ogp page when User-agent matches Twitter or Facebook.

My redirect image is like this.

```
/news/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/informations/ogp/1?lang=ja
/news/detail.html?id=1&lang=en -> /api/v1/informations/ogp/1?lang=en

/sport/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/sports/ogp/1?lang=ja
/sport/detail.html?id=1&lang=en -> /api/v1/sports/ogp/1?lang=en

/event/common/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/events/ogp/1?lang=ja
/event/common/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/events/ogp/1?lang=ja
/event/special/detail.html?id=2&lang=en -> /api/v1/events/ogp/2?lang=en
/event/special/detail.html?id=2 -> /api/v1/events/ogp/2?lang=ja
```

So I wrote htaccess, Env params work ok, but rewrite rule does not work when RewriteRule takes two or more over.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^facebookexternalhit.*$" UA_FACEBOOK=1
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^facebookplatform.*$" UA_FACEBOOK=1
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Twitterbot.*$" UA_TWITTER=1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)&lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^news/detail.html$ /api/v1/informations/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^sport/detail.html$ /api/v1/sports/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^event/common/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^event/special/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^news/detail.html$ /api/v1/informations/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^sport/detail.html$ /api/v1/sports/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^event/common/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^event/special/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to redirect them all with same RewriteCond, how to do that?

Even dirty code is welcome!

Comment: RewriteConds only ever work on the RewriteRule that immediately follows them. Next RewriteRule after the first - completely independent from any conditions.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap all your RewriteRules into an `<If>` block, similar to how it is suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23898519/1427878 See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html for more examples & syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> /news/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/informations/ogp/1?lang=ja
> /news/detail.html?id=1&lang=en -> /api/v1/informations/ogp/1?lang=en
>
> /sport/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/sports/ogp/1?lang=ja
> /sport/detail.html?id=1&lang=en -> /api/v1/sports/ogp/1?lang=en
>
> /event/common/detail.html?id=1 -> /api/v1/events/ogp/1?lang=ja
> /event/common/detail.html?id=1&lang=en -> /api/v1/events/ogp/1?lang=en
>
> /event/special/detail.html?id=2 -> /api/v1/events/ogp/2?lang=ja
> /event/special/detail.html?id=2&lang=en -> /api/v1/events/ogp/2?lang=en
> ```

This is really only 4 URL mappings (when the `lang` param is omitted it assigned a default - the target remains the same), so you only need 4 rules (if you extract the `lang` param). And the last 2 redirect to the same target so these can be easily combined (using regex alternation `(common|special)`), leaving just 3 separate rules that are required.

You could do it like this to avoid any repetition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/v1

# Get "lang" (default to "ja")
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:ja]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(\w+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:%1]

# Get "id" (if any)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ID:%1]

# If not Facebook|Twitter OR no ID then skip the next 3 rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebook(externalhit|platform)|twitterbot) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:ID} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [S=3]

# If here then Facebook|Twitter and "id" param are passed, LANG already set
RewriteRule ^news/detail\.html$ informations/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^sport/detail\.html$ sports/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^event/(common|special)/detail\.html$ events/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
```

The trick here is the use of the `S` (`skip`) flag to skip over the following 3 rules when the User-Agent is *not* Facebook or Twitter (or there is no `id` URL param present) - reversing the logic. Which means that the last 3 rules are only processed when the User-Agent *is* Facebook or Twitter and the `id` URL param is present.

Note that I used non-capturing subpatterns to ensure that the backreferences (ie. `%1`) only refer to the group we are interested in.

NB: I changed the `RewriteBase` to "simplify" the last 3 rules. Although if you have other directives then you may want to change this back.

> I tried the method of using the If directive, but it didn't work

Your current rules would have failed to match inside an `<If>` directive (Apache 2.4), because in this *context* the `RewriteRule` directive matches against the absolute file-path, not a relative URL-path (probably because `<If>` containers are merged *very* late).

Providing there are no conflicts, a simple workaround here is to just remove the start-of-string anchor (`^`) from the start of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* so as to be able to match a file-path of the form `/absolute/file/path/to/public_html/news/detail.php`. (Although I would probably add a slash prefix in order to avoid any partial path-segment matches.)

So, you could potentially write it like this instead using an `<If>` expression:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Get "id" (if any)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ID:%1]

# Facebook|Twitter AND "id" param are passed
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /^(?i)(facebook(externalhit|platform)|twitterbot)/ && reqenv('ID') =~ /\d+/">
    # Get "lang" (default to "ja")
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:ja]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=LANG:%1]

    # Redirects
    RewriteRule /news/detail\.html$ /api/v1/informations/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
    RewriteRule /sport/detail\.html$ /api/v1/sports/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
    RewriteRule /event/(common|special)/detail\.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%{ENV:ID}?lang=%{ENV:LANG} [R,L]
</If>
```

Comment: Those codes work perfectly! You saved my project from dirty large codes. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This dirty code did what I wanted it to do.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^facebookexternalhit.*$" UA_FACEBOOK=1
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^facebookplatform.*$" UA_FACEBOOK=1
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Twitterbot.*$" UA_TWITTER=1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)&lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^news/detail.html$ /api/v1/informations/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)&lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^sport/detail.html$ /api/v1/sports/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)&lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^event/common/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)&lang=(\w+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^event/special/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=%3 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^news/detail.html$ /api/v1/informations/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^sport/detail.html$ /api/v1/sports/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^event/common/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} ^1$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} ^1$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=(\d+)($|&)
    RewriteRule ^event/special/detail.html$ /api/v1/events/ogp/%2?lang=ja [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried the method of using the If directive, but it didn't work with my environment variable like below code

```
<If "%{ENV:UA_FACEBOOK} -eq 1 || %{ENV:UA_TWITTER} -eq 1"></If>
```

so I solved this problem by writing a lot of same RewriteCond again and again.

If you have a better way to write this, I welcome it.